# Can you remove all the extra arithmetic from ZFC (or other theories)?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, peano-arithmetic, metamathematics

Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the standard model of the natural numbers. For any statement in the language of arithmetic, we can translate into a statement in the language of set theory by asking if it is true of $\mathbb{N}$.

Let's say that a statement in arithmetic is "extraneous" if it is independent of PA. For example, ZFC proves Con(PA), which is extraneous.

My question is, is there a set of statements $S$ (in the language of set theory), such that $S$ proves no extraneous statements, and $S+PA=ZFC$ (or perhaps $S+PA \vdash ZFC$).

Edit: We can also consider the same question, but with PA replaced with the set of arithmetical statements provable in ZFC.

Comment: I think this question is a bit muddled in its language. What does 'independent of PA' mean in a non-arithmetic context? For instance, the statement 'For any two sets $x,y$ there exists the set $\{x,y\}$ is 'independent of $PA$'. Is that not innately an extraneous statement?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki "that a statement in *arithmetic*" That isn't an arithmetical statement.

Comment: What do you mean by $S+PA=ZFC$? $\mathsf{PA} $ and $\mathsf{ZFC}$ are stated in different languages. Or do you  mean the translation of  $\mathsf{PA}$ to the language of set theory rather than $\mathsf{PA}$ itself? What precisely is that translation? A straightforward version replaces each $\phi $ with the claim that $\mathbb N $ satisfies $\phi $, but then the translation of $\mathsf{PA}$ witnesses the consistency of $\mathsf{PA}$.

Comment: What makes PA so privileged for you, that you say something not provable in PA is extraneous? After all, we have many much stronger and very natural theories, such as the various strong set theories and large cardinal axioms, that have arithmetic consequences not provable in PA. In this sense, PA can be viewed as a weak, primitive theory; we have much better theories now.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I didn't mean for it to have a negative connotation. I just wanted to pick some statements of arithmetic, and PA was the first thing I thought of. The set of tautologies or set of arithmetical theorems of ZFC would also be interesting.

Comment: I'm not objecting to any negative connotation. Rather, just wondering why the question is fixated on not proving anything beyond PA, which in the realm of set theory is a very weak theory. Even ZFC counts as weak in the context of large cardinals.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I was afraid that demanding something to strong would leave $S$ to be too weak. I think I may have gotten my intuitions backwards though, and that we actually do want our theory of arithmetic to be strong, as noted by Sridhar Ramesh.

Comment: @Andres: We can translate each claim about natural numbers into a claim about finite ordinals, and thus turn sentences in the language of arithmetic into sentences in the language of set theory, to turn PA into a theory in the language of set theory which is strictly weaker than ZFC and in particular which does not itself prove Con(PA) in any standard sense.

Comment: @Sridhar The translation is precisely saying that $\omega\models\mathsf{PA}$.

Comment: We could carry out this translation even in the context of a set theory with no axiom of infinity, which would fail to prove Con(PA).

Comment: @Sridhar Yes, but that is not the context here. (By the way, you may enjoy reading [this](https://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2013/08/18/interpretations/).)

Comment: I think you are looking for the fact that ZFC-Infinity is equivalent to PA in a very strong sense.

Comment: @Andres: Isn't that the context here? That's all it takes to consider the question of whether S + PA = ZFC makes sense; start with a weak set theory which does not prove any arithmetic statement PA does not, and consider whether one can find S such that that base set theory + S + (the appropriate translation of all the statements of) PA = ZFC. It seems clear enough what the questioner is asking and how to make sense of it.

Comment: Though, as I noted in comment on my answer below, I believe the question they in some sense implicitly meant to ask was a different one than the one they did ask (if that makes sense…).

Comment: @Sridhar No, that is not the context of the original version of the question. Yes, obviously something nontrivial can be salvaged from that version. I am not discussing that, or your interpretation of the actual intention of the question, only what was explicitly written originally. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 12):

If $S$ proves no "extraneous" statements, then $S$ cannot prove $X \rightarrow Con(PA)$ for any arithmetic statement $X$ which $PA$ proves. It follows that $S + PA$ cannot prove $Con(PA)$, and therefore $S + PA$ cannot entail all of $ZFC$.

Comment: I would suggest that perhaps more in the spirit of what I would've thought this question would be would be to search for some S and some T such that S proves no extraneous statements, T consists only of arithmetic statements, and S + T = ZFC. Without loss of generality, we may even take T to consist of all arithmetic consequences of ZFC. I suspect no suitable S can be found, but do not know a proof at the moment.

Comment: actually yeah, I like that question better.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for ZFC without the Axiom of Infinity, leaving the heriditarily finite sets.  This proves the same arithmetic theorems as PA, if I understand it right.